# Исчезли 2 блока с контентом

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте.

Такая проблема: в один день исчезли 2 блока с контентом, которые получают информацию из базы данных MySQL. Слева было меню, которое соответствует таблицам в БД, и основной блок - там были новости из одной из таблиц. Но в хедере есть кнопки, которые ссылаются на БД, и они открываются. Вот сайт - http://zhodino-edu.belhost.by/.

Буду признателен за любой совет. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Привет! Предоставь код, что ли. А то это как на кофе гадать.

Comment: код? Этот что-ли?

<?php
include ("blocks/db.php");
include ("left/about.php");
include ("left/uchrmenu.php");
include ("left/menu.php");
include ("left/proformenu.php");
include ("left/archivmenu.php");
include ("left/profsouz.php");


$page=implode('',file('left_block.tpl'));





$page=str_replace('{ABOUT}',$a,$page);

$page=str_replace('{UCHR}',$u,$page);

$page=str_replace('{MENU}',$m,$page);

$page=str_replace('{PROFOR}',$o,$page);

$page=str_replace('{ARCHIV}',$r,$page);

$page=str_replace('{PROFSOUZ}',$b,$page);



echo $page;
?>

Answer (score 1):

У вас что-то с настройками mod_php в apache случилось. Ваш index.php не обрабатывается сервером как php-файл. Он отдается клиенту as-is.
Посмотрите в error.log сервера - возможно там найдете причину. Если сами не сможете решить проблему - могу попробовать помочь.